# Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5 15IIL05 Won't Charge

Tags: laptop, battery, power, lenovo-laptop

Just over a year ago, I bought a Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5 15IIL05. Unfortunately, it has recently started having issues, possibly with the battery.

First, several months ago it started randomly restarting. It seemed as if the battery had been momentarily disconnected and reconnected. I physically disconnected and reconnected the battery, which helped for a few days, but it has since restarted every day no matter what I do.

Second, it has recently periodically stopped charging. On a regular basis (once a day or so) when a USB-PD charger is plugged into the USB-C port, the light doesn't come on and Windows doesn't report it as being plugged in. This has happened with multiple USB-C chargers, though I do not have a barrel jack charger to test that out. It is not a driver or software problem because I booted into a live Linux USB drive while the problem was happening and it continued happening. The only solution that I found was disconnecting and reconnecting the battery, which delays the problem for a day. I have tried a static discharge (pressing the power button for a minute while the battery is unplugged), but it helped for two days then stopped making a difference.

All of the drivers and firmware are fully updated with Lenovo Vantage. I wanted to test some contact points with my multimeter to see if PD negotiation had happened, but I was unable to find any points without removing the logic board, which I don't want to do while the battery is plugged in. It's definitely not a software problem as Linux has the same problem as Windows, so it's probably either firmware or hardware. Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...  This has happened with multiple USB-C chargers, though I do not
> have a barrel jack charger to test that out.

This appears to be a battery failure.

See if you can do a Battery Reset.

Charge to full charge. This may be problematic based on your description. Get a barrel jack charger if you can.

Once charged, disconnect the charger and and allow the battery to drain.

Once that is done, charge to full and see if the battery works properly.

If not, replace the battery.

Comment: Thank you! I can't be sure if this works yet, but once I find out I'll accept this answer.

Comment: The battery reset worked. Thank you.

Comment: the battery reset procedure is quite useful.